# Java regex pattern query

Tags: java, regex

Just a quick question about Java regex patterns! So say if I had a method like..

```
    public void example()
    {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
      Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
      boolean b = false;
      while (b = m.find()) 
      {
        System.out.println(m.start() + " " + m.group()); 
      }
    }
```

If I ran this I would end up with the following output..

```
     0
     1
     2 34
     4
     5
     6
```

I understand how this works apart from how it ends up at 6, I thought it would finish on 5 could someone please explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: 6 is for the empty character at the end.

Comment: BTW your `b` is entirely redundant. You never read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your string, `"ab34ef"`, there are 7 "empty characters" with a value of `""`. They are located between each of the normal characters. It attempts to find a match starting on each *empty* character, not each normal character; i.e. the location of each `|` in the following: `"|a|b|3|4|e|f|"`.